How to get the list of Ethereum phishing accounts?
For my research, I need to get the list of both phishing and non-phishing accounts on Ethereum blockchain. How do I use python crawler to get the list?

You'd need to decide what constitutes phishing, and then parse every block filtering for activity that matched your definition. Else you could try and obtain whatever list a given explorer is using, they will have accepted reports and claims from various known groups in the space. Sometimes there is collateral damage (addresses mislabeled), as there probably would be with whatever filter you designed yourself.
